# Prevent IEEEeqnarray ignoring baselineskip

Tags: line-spacing

I have been running into this problem when using `\IEEEeqnarray`. I have set the default line spacing of my document to be `\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt`, however for any paragraphs before an equation array this command is seemingly ignored, but all paragraphs after are fine.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt

Here is some text. This text is normal and spaced how I would like for it to be spaced. I am going to add a few more words to make it really clear what the spacing is meant to look like. Notice how the lines are relatively further apart compare to the following paragraph.

Here is some text. It is spaced too narrowly. This text is not spaced correctly since immediately after I am going to use the command \verb=\IEEEeqnarray=. For some reason I cannot understand it overrides the spacing I set up earlier.
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
    (a + b) + c & =  & a + b + c \\
    & = & a + (b + c)
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

This text after is also formatted correctly. The purpose of this text is to show that the affected text is only for paragraphs directly before the \verb=\IEEEeqnarray= environment.

\end{document}
```

[image: This is what the result looks like.]

Is there any way to resolve this? I would like to be able to use `\IEEEeqnarray` since it is very useful but this makes my document look really ugly.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for posting a (slightly too) minimal document. Could you add a `\documentclass{...}` (presumably one of the IEEE classes) to make the document compilable?

Comment: I had just been using ```\documentclass{article}``` but I have edited anyway to include my entire preamble.

Comment: Simply putting a blank line before the array environment solves the problem, no? Or using the `{setspace}` package to change the line spacing, instead of messing with `\baselineskip`.

Comment: It does but the blank line shows up in the compiled document. So I would have a bunch of equations with blank space before them. If there is a way to include a phantom blank line this would also solve the problem I suppose

Comment: Ok ```{setspace}``` works! Just need to figure out the spacing to match ```\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt```. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `IEEEeqnarray` sets `\baselineskip` to `\normalbaselineskip`, which you don't set.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \baselineskip=18pt plus1pt
  \normalbaselineskip=18pt plus1pt
  \selectfont
}

\begin{document}

Here is some text. This text is normal and spaced how I would like for
it to be spaced. I am going to add a few more words to make it really
clear what the spacing is meant to look like. Notice how the lines
are relatively further apart compare to the following paragraph.

Here is some text. It is spaced too narrowly. This text is not spaced
correctly since immediately after I am going to use the command
\verb=\IEEEeqnarray=. For some reason I cannot understand it overrides
the spacing I set up earlier.
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
    (a + b) + c & =  & a + b + c \\
    & = & a + (b + c)
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

This text after is also formatted correctly. The purpose of this
text is to show that the affected text is only for paragraphs
directly before the \verb=\IEEEeqnarray= environment.

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, using flexible baseline skip is not the best idea. It's much better if you ensure an integer number of lines, which is easy to do with the `geometry` package and with `\linespread{1.5}`.

Comment: Thanks, both suggestions resolve the problem. Why is it better to use ```\linespread{1.5}```? It seems to adjust my margins.  I'm not sure what you mean by ensuring an integer number of lines.